# Spring Security+Spring 4- Disable muti login for same user

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-boot

I have the below spring configuration :-

```
@Override
    protected void configure(
        final HttpSecurity http)
        throws Exception {

      http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and()
          .formLogin().loginPage("/login").defaultSuccessUrl("/home")
          .permitAll().and().logout().permitAll()
          .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
          .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout").permitAll().and()
          .httpBasic().and()
          .exceptionHandling()
          .accessDeniedPage("/error").and()
          .sessionManagement().maximumSessions(1);   
    }
```

I was expecting `sessionManagement().maximumSessions(1)` to disable multiple login for the same user. But I am still able to login from different tabs of the same browser.

Kindly request you to let me know where its going wrong.

Comment: Try a different browser/incognito mode, your tabs are sharing cookies and therefore don't count as additional sessions.

Comment: I will check on  forcing disabling cokkies sharing for this application.

Comment: have you added HttpSessionEventPublisher listener in web.xml without it it wont work.if you want i will post the code

Comment: I am using spring boot and do not have web.xml..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this in your @Configuration class

```
@Bean
public ServletListenerRegistrationBean<HttpSessionEventPublisher> httpSessionEventPublisher() {
    return new ServletListenerRegistrationBean<HttpSessionEventPublisher>(new HttpSessionEventPublisher());
}
```